# How do I know the Webrtc revision and version number?

Tags: android, git, webrtc

I have built the webrtc for android using the [Pristine IO](http://pristine.io) web srcipts from here https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-build-scripts. I have cloned the git repo of webrtc also, but don't see any tagged releases of it anywhere. In fact I don't see even a single tag and only 2-3 branches other than master.

My question is how do people generally version their webrtc builds? Is it solely dependent on git commit sha only?

---

**Edit:** generated files are

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi @vKashyap usually the version is a part of the path or a library name (the output file after building) and it should look in your case like this: ./webrtc-build-scripts/ios/webrtc/libWebRTC-LATEST-Universal-Debug.a.version.txt

Moreover to fetch and build a particular version you can check the following guide:
https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code/working-with-release-branches

Comment: Unfortunately in case of android you don't get the version number files. I have pasted the generated folder structure in question.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to do things if you use the scripts provided by webrtc.org directly. Everything is simplified now as per as steps are concerned for building webrtc. See https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/

The webrtc.org code uses git so you can do the following (after you have done `fetch --nohooks webrtc_android` or equivalent steps) to get the tags:

```
git fetch --tags
```

Once you get the tags, you can switch to any tagged branch using `git checkout` for e.g.

```
git checkout branch-heads/55
```

The above command will checkout webrtc code equivalent to chrome 55. Then you can follow webrtc.org instructions to build.

Comment: Well I fetched the tags but it doesn't contain any tag. Though the build script does spill up the revision number.

Comment: If you do "git tag", it will show the tags it fetched.